# Creating a sitemap/index page, ordered by A-Z and 0-9

Tags: templating, navigation, order

I'm created an Index like page (like at the back of a book) for entries within a certain section, ordered alphabetically with the letter proceeding it.

My code below seems like a tedious way to do it, is their an easier way?

How would I handle the entries with a number as the first character (0-9) of the title?

```
     <h2>A</h2>

     <ul class="sub-nav">
      {% for entry in craft.entries.section('artists').search('title::A*').order('title').find() %}
        <li>...</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    <h2>B</h2>

     <ul class="sub-nav">
      {% for entry in craft.entries.section('artists').search('title::B*').order('title').find() %}
        <li>...</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>


    <h2>C</h2>

     <ul class="sub-nav">
      {% for entry in craft.entries.section('artists').search('title::C*').order('title').find() %}
        <li>...</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is with the [group](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter. You want to group the entries by the first character of the title.

Get the entries as an actual array

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('artists').order('title').find %}
```

Group them by first letter of title. [first](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/first.html) will return the first character of a string. [upper](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/upper.html) converts a string to uppercase.

```
{% set groupedEntries = allEntries|group('title|first|upper') %}
```

Now you can loop through them:

```
{% for index, values in groupedEntries %}
  <h2>{{index}}</h2>
  <ul class="sub-nav">
    {% for e in values %}
      <li>...{{e}}...</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

See also [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/how-can-i-group-a-list-of-tags-into-ranges-of-first-letters-a-e-f-j-etc).

Comment: Thanks! Edited that slightly to:
{% set entriesGrouped = allEntries|group('title|slice(0, 1)|upper|replace("/[^A-Z]/", "0-9")') %}
to get 0-9 rather then 0,1,2 etc.