# Alphabetical index for a list of entries

Tags: templating, filter, array

I would like to build an alphabetical list of craft entries, but group them by the initials of one field of each entry. Thus, getting some kind of alphabetical index, like

A

- Apples
- Ananas

B

- Beer

How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, sort all entries by multiple criteria:

```
{# get our entries and order by firstname, lastname #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('entries').orderBy('lastname asc, firstname asc').all() %}
```

Then use craft's custom "group" filter (`lastname[:1]` picks the first letter):

```
{# group them by the first letter of the last name https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#group #}
{% set allEntriesByGroup = allEntries | group('lastname[:1]') %}
```

Then loop through that multidimensional array (`firstletter, entriesInGroup`) is `key -> value` in twig:

```
{% for firstletter, entriesInGroup in allEntriesByGroup %}
    <h3>{{firstletter}}</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entriesInGroup %}
       <li>{{entry.lastname}}, {{entry.firstname}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The reason I'm posting it is I first thought I had to do the array manipulation in twig – but then found out twig doesn't really support that, by design – and finally, found out craft provides a great set of tools on top of twig like those custom filters

Comment: Here's another option from a previous SE thread: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/22397/278 (not updated for Craft 3).