# Grouping entries by title in Craft 3

Tags: search, craft3

I need to group a set of entries alphabetically and I don't get a working and clean solution.
Taking [this documentation entry](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching), I am doing it as follows:

```
  {% set fromAtoF = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:a* OR A* OR b* OR B* OR c* OR C* OR d* OR D* OR e* OR E* OR f* OR F*') %}
  {% set fromGtoL = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:g* OR G* OR h* OR H* OR i* OR I* OR j* OR J* OR k* OR K* OR l* OR L*') %}
  {% set fromMtoR = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:m* OR M* OR n* OR N* OR o* OR O* OR p* OR P* OR q* OR Q* OR r* OR R*') %}
  {% set fromStoZ = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:s* OR S* OR t* OR T* OR u* OR U* OR v* OR V* OR w* OR W* OR x* OR X* OR y* OR Y* OR z* OR Z*') %}
```

- **Problem 1**: I get entries starting by 'A' like 'Amazon' in the `fromStoZ` group, and 'Walmart' in `fromGToL`...etc
- **Problem 2**: It's not clean nor elegant. There must be other ways to query this but I haven't found the good one yet.

I also tried:

```
  {% set fromAtoF = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:a* OR b* OR title:c* OR title:d* OR title:e* OR title:f*') %}
  {% set fromGtoL = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:g* OR title:h* OR title:i* OR title:j* OR title:k* OR title:l*') %}
  {% set fromMtoR = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:m* OR title:n* OR title:o* OR title:p* OR title:q* OR title:r*') %}
  {% set fromStoZ = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').order('title').search('title:s* OR title:t* OR title:u* OR title:w* OR title:x* OR title:y* OR title:z*') %}
```

But neither it works; entries like 'Best Buy' and 'JC Penney' don't get into any group, but 'Best Buy2' goes correctly into fromAtoF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of solutions provided:

```
 {% set groupedShops = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops')
                    .order('title').all() |
                    group("title|first|upper |
                    replace('/[A-F]/', 'A to F', 1) |
                    replace('/[G-L]/', 'G to L', 1) |
                    replace('/[M-R]/', 'M to R', 1) |
                    replace('/[S-Z]/', 'S to Z', 1)") %}
```

Then you can do:

```
  {% for groupName, group in groupedShops %}
      <h1> {{ groupName }} </h1>
      <ul>
        {% for shop in group %}
          <li> {{ shop.title }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

Then you have:

**A to F:**

- Amazon
- Best Buy

**G to L:**

- Happy Shops
- Hollister
- Luxe DH

...etc

A very similar query is explained here:

[How can I group a list of tags into ranges of first letters (A–E, F–J, etc.)?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/how-can-i-group-a-list-of-tags-into-ranges-of-first-letters-a-e-f-j-etc)

Important detail pointed by @Carlcs:

> In Craft 3 you need to explicitly query for the entries using **all()** method on the elment query object

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do with this data, but it sounds like you could use the [group filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group)

```
{% set alphaEntries = craft.entries.section('shops').type('shops').all() | group('title | slice(0, 1)') %}

{% for letter, entries in alphaEntries %}
    <h2>{{ letter }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for answering. What I need is to group shops into alphabetical groups like:
_From A to F_:
Amazon, Best Buy, Carrefour
_From G to L_:
H&M, IceLand
... etc
The answer you gave me throws the error: **Argument 1 passed to craft\web\twig\Extension::groupFilter() must be of the type array**..

Comment: @RosanaRuiz in Craft 3 you need to explicitly query for the entries using `all()` method on the elment query object. That change should make the `group` filter happy!